# In page anchor linking causes entire content div to move

Tags: html, css, scroll, anchor

Such a strange issue...

http://www.casterconcepts.com/caster-wheels/cast-iron-wheels/ (click "View Series" as an example)

Whenever (site-wide) an anchor is clicked on, rather than JUST moving the screenspace to the proper ID, it shifts the entire content div up and out of site.

I for the life of me cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the css lines in #main:after. Absolute position and width with percentage value causing to slide an be hidden by #main's overflow control.

```
#main {
    width:1000px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 10px;
}

#main:after {
    content:" ";
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    background:#fff;
    left:10px;
    top:0;
    height:50000px;
    box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would never have thought that. I was doing that as a way of creating a pseudo column background in order to have the main content column stretch all the way down, even when the sidebar is taller.